# Получить значение из ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть коллекция Dictionary(string,int) которая привязана к ComboBox. При выборе 1 из пунктов в ComboBox мне необходимо положить значения взятые из него в разные переменные. Со string я разобрался (var str=ComboBox1.Text;) а вот как со значением типа int сложности.
Как можно решить этот вопрос?

Comment: `myDictionary[str]`

Answer (score 0):

Код исключительно для примера:

```
 var intValue = convertToInt32(dictonary.where(p => 
 p.Value.Contains(textBox1.Text))
```

Поиск по ключу словаря

```
 var intValue = ConvertToInt32(dictonary.FirstOrDefult(x => x.Value == xValue).Key);
```